# sqlite error while integrating facebook in ios

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook-login

I am integrating Facebook login in my app. Gone through links 
[Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/)
but when I compile I get following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
  -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
  -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
  -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _readEntriesFromDatabase:excludingFragment:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
  ___23-[FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
  -[FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
  -[FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
  -[FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
  _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  -[FBCacheIndex _readEntriesFromDatabase:excludingFragment:] in  FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   ...   "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
   ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
   _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
   ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
   _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
   _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)   "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
   -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _createCacheEntityInfo:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
   ... ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

I have also added `-Isqlite3.0` reference in *other linking flags* of *Build Settings* tab for the project, but am still getting the error. What am I doing wrong? Using XCode 4.5 with iOS6.

Comment: Have u added all necessary frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also have to link your app to the sqlite library or CoreData.framework, depending on what their documentation says is needed.